# Visual Studio 2015 dropdown to find procedure in a class

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Just installed `Visual Studio 2015` and can't find nowhere how to show the dropdowns to quickly find a specific function or procedure inside a class.

[image]

Comment: I can see the dropdown in the posted pic though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not found then set it following below steps

> Click on Tools -> Options
>
> Select Text Editor -> All Languages and check the *Navigation Bar*
> check box

[image]